# How to create xml webservice DTOs depending on conditions?

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services

Is it possible to create a global `DTO` for an xml webservice, but having conditional fields inside?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class MyDTO {
    ...
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name = "somename")
    private List<String> list;
}
```

Now, what if I want to release another version of the webservice, and rename the `@XmlElement` field thereby (or introduce additional fields, remove some, etc).

So that backwards compatibility is retained, but the same objects are used for the "new" version.

I could maybe do this my adding request path methods with `/v1`, `/v2` etc.
But how could I then maintain a single DTO class, but with fields conditional on the version path?

Or would I always have to duplicate those `DTO` classes and modify exactly to me needs of the version?

```
@RestController
public void MyServlet {
    @RequestMapping("/v1")
    public MyDTO1 request1() {

    }

    @RequestMapping("/v2")
    public MyDTO2 request2() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer using tailored DTOs for each version of the API. To avoid boilerplate code when mapping your entities to DTOs, you could consider using mapping frameworks such as [MapStruct](http://mapstruct.org/).

If you are using Jackson, you could consider using JSON Views (they will work with XML too). Quoting from the [*Latest Jackson integration improvements in Spring*](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#json-views) article:

> ### [JSON Views](https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring#json-views)
>
> It can sometimes be useful to filter contextually objects serialized to the HTTP response body. In order to provide such capabilities, Spring MVC now has builtin support for [Jackson’s Serialization Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) (as of Spring Framework 4.2, JSON Views are supported on `@MessageMapping` handler methods as well).
>
> The following example illustrates how to use `@JsonView` to filter fields depending on the context of serialization - e.g. getting a “summary” view when dealing with collections, and getting a full representation when dealing with a single resource:
>
> ```java
> public class View {
>     interface Summary {}
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> public class User {
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private Long id;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private String firstname;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private String lastname;
>
>     private String email;
>     private String address;
>     private String postalCode;
>     private String city;
>     private String country;
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> public class Message {
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private Long id;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private LocalDate created;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private String title;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private User author;
>
>     private List<User> recipients;
>
>     private String body;
> }
> ```
>
> Thanks to Spring MVC `@JsonView` support, it is possible to choose, on a per handler method basis, which field should be serialized:
>
> ```java
> @RestController
> public class MessageController {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private MessageService messageService;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     @RequestMapping("/")
>     public List<Message> getAllMessages() {
>         return messageService.getAll();
>     }
>
>     @RequestMapping("/{id}")
>     public Message getMessage(@PathVariable Long id) {
>         return messageService.get(id);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In this example, if all messages are retrieved, only the most important fields are serialized thanks to the `getAllMessages()` method annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)`:
>
> ```json
> [ {
>   "id" : 1,
>   "created" : "2014-11-14",
>   "title" : "Info",
>   "author" : {
>     "id" : 1,
>     "firstname" : "Brian",
>     "lastname" : "Clozel"
>   }
> }, {
>   "id" : 2,
>   "created" : "2014-11-14",
>   "title" : "Warning",
>   "author" : {
>     "id" : 2,
>     "firstname" : "Stéphane",
>     "lastname" : "Nicoll"
>   }
> }, {
>   "id" : 3,
>   "created" : "2014-11-14",
>   "title" : "Alert",
>   "author" : {
>     "id" : 3,
>     "firstname" : "Rossen",
>     "lastname" : "Stoyanchev"
>   }
> } ]
> ```
>
> In Spring MVC default configuration, `MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION` is set to `false`. That means that when enabling a JSON View, non annotated fields or properties like body or recipients are not serialized.
>
> When a specific `Message` is retrieved using the `getMessage()` handler method (no JSON View specified), all fields are serialized as expected:
>
> ```json
> {
>   "id" : 1,
>   "created" : "2014-11-14",
>   "title" : "Info",
>   "body" : "This is an information message",
>   "author" : {
>     "id" : 1,
>     "firstname" : "Brian",
>     "lastname" : "Clozel",
>     "email" : "bclozel@pivotal.io",
>     "address" : "1 Jaures street",
>     "postalCode" : "69003",
>     "city" : "Lyon",
>     "country" : "France"
>   },
>   "recipients" : [ {
>     "id" : 2,
>     "firstname" : "Stéphane",
>     "lastname" : "Nicoll",
>     "email" : "snicoll@pivotal.io",
>     "address" : "42 Obama street",
>     "postalCode" : "1000",
>     "city" : "Brussel",
>     "country" : "Belgium"
>   }, {
>     "id" : 3,
>     "firstname" : "Rossen",
>     "lastname" : "Stoyanchev",
>     "email" : "rstoyanchev@pivotal.io",
>     "address" : "3 Warren street",
>     "postalCode" : "10011",
>     "city" : "New York",
>     "country" : "USA"
>   } ]
> }
> ```
>
> Only one class or interface can be specified with the `@JsonView` annotation, but you can use inheritance to represent JSON View hierarchies (if a field is part of a JSON View, it will be also part of parent view). For example, this handler method will serialize fields annotated with `@JsonView(View.Summary.class)` and `@JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)`:
>
> ```java
> public class View {
>     interface Summary {}
>     interface SummaryWithRecipients extends Summary {}
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> public class Message {
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private Long id;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private LocalDate created;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private String title;
>
>     @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
>     private User author;
>
>     @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
>     private List<User> recipients;
>
>     private String body;
> }
> ```
>
> ```java
> @RestController
> public class MessageController {
>
>     @Autowired
>     private MessageService messageService;
>
>     @JsonView(View.SummaryWithRecipients.class)
>     @RequestMapping("/with-recipients")
>     public List<Message> getAllMessagesWithRecipients() {
>         return messageService.getAll();
>     }
> }
> ```